# async Programming Issues

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-ctp

I've recently discovered the CTP Async Library and I wanted to try to write a toy program to get familiar with the new concepts, however I'm running into an issue.

I believe the code should write out

```
Starting
stuff in the middle
task string
```

but it's not.  Here's the code I'm running with:

```
namespace TestingAsync
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AsyncTest a = new AsyncTest();
            a.MethodAsync();
        }
    }

    class AsyncTest
    {
        async public void MethodAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting");
            string test = await Slow();
            Console.WriteLine("stuff in the middle");
            Console.WriteLine(test);
        }

        private async Task<string> Slow()
        {
            await TaskEx.Delay(5000);
            return "task string";
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?  It would be awesome if someone knew of some good tutorials and/or videos demonstrating the concepts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling an async method, but then just letting your application finish. Options:

- Add `Thread.Sleep` (or Console.ReadLine) to your `Main` method, so that you can sleep while the async stuff happens on background threads
- Make your async method return `Task` and wait on that from your `Main` method.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AsyncTest a = new AsyncTest();
        Task task = a.MethodAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting in Main thread");
        task.Wait();
    }
}

class AsyncTest
{
    public async Task MethodAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting");
        string test = await Slow();
        Console.WriteLine("stuff in the middle");
        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }

    private async Task<string> Slow()
    {
        await TaskEx.Delay(5000);
        return "task string";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Starting
Waiting in Main thread
stuff in the middle
task string
```

In terms of videos, I did a session on async earlier in the year at Progressive .NET - [the video is online](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/home/async-methods/js-2648). Additionally, I have a number of [blog posts about async](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/async/default.aspx), including my [Eduasync](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Eduasync/default.aspx) series.

Additionally there are lots of videos and blog posts from the team at Microsoft. See the [Async Home Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360) for lots of resources.

Comment: Your second option is what I was looking for.  After making `MethodAsync()` return `Task`, I was able to call `a.MethodAsync().wait();` from `Main`, and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You're program exits before the 5000ms is up.